# Настройка сервера через vnc

Tags: php, gnu

Хостинг предоставил ssh и vnc все рутовое

GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

подскажите где можно почитать про настройку сервера на этой системе

буду поднимать опенкарт
т.е. нужен apache, ftp, php, zip, curl, msyql

Comment: в сети очень много руководств. вы можете открыть документацию по каждому из перечисленных продуктов и найдете там как их устанавливать. например, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4QBjJOakAo

Comment: Спасибо за направление
вот чего еще удалось насобирать 
https://linuxconfig.org/apache-webserver-httpd-service-installation-on-redhat-7-linux


https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-centos-7/


https://serveradmin.ru/ustanovit-i-nastroit-phpmyadmin-na-centos-7/


https://serveradmin.ru/ustanovka-lamp-apache-php-mysql-v-centos-7/

и привязка домена к айпи 
https://vps.ua/wiki/install-linux-vps/web-servers/apache/how-link-domain/

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0):

Тот минимум что понадобился, мне для запуска opencart на сервере CentOS 7

[Установка phpmyadmin на CentOS 7](https://serveradmin.ru/ustanovit-i-nastroit-phpmyadmin-na-centos-7/)

[Настройка web сервера в CentOS 7](https://serveradmin.ru/ustanovka-lamp-apache-php-mysql-v-centos-7/)

[Как привязать домен к сайту](https://vps.ua/wiki/install-linux-vps/web-servers/apache/how-link-domain/)